# C++: Why can't functions' parameters be auto?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

For example,  following codes won't be accepted

```
void foo(auto i){
    cout<<(i+1);
}
```

I think that it should be  equivalent to the following accepted codes

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T i){
    cout<<(i+1);
}
```

So the compiler should be able to deduce(or instantiate) the type of the parameters.
But why wouldn't it work?

Thx a lot :-)

Comment: You can write `auto foo = [](auto i) { cout << (i+1); };`

Comment: Perhaps in the future, considering the current solution isn't perfect (e.g., it won't work with `constexpr`), but for now, there are polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: Because the standard doesn't allow it. The current working draft of the Concepts TS does permit this.

Comment: Note that the use of `auto` in C++ is fairly recent, and the use of `auto` for a function argument even more so (only approved into the standard C++ a few weeks back). Deduced return types for functions have been adopted in C++14, and this is not far from that, but I could see how this overlaps with the concepts proposals so the solution to those might be a better alternative than using `auto` here… Wrote this as a comment and voted to close as this is mostly opinion based (unless the answer you want is *because the standard doesn't allow it*, which is a hard fact.

Comment: I believe because they're going to add Concept (in C++17) which will simplify the syntax and goes one step ahead improving template (or auto), which is why they didn't consider adding `auto` as function parameter type. It is allowed in lambdas though, because lambdas feels more local to the code compared to function.

Comment: @Nawaz I thought that was only in C++1y (not C++11)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, thats not possible in C++11. But then now [**we have C++14!**](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/08/we-have-cpp14) ... and both clang and gcc has already implemented almost all features.